# Spring 21 LWC Quick Action Release

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'am creating a lightning web component as quick action based on the Spring '21 [release](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_action.htm&type=5&release=230) . I'm using an `actionType` of ScreenAction. My problem is that in `connectedCallback` the attribute `recordId` is still undefined. However, `recordId` has value when my button is clicked. I need the value of the `recordId` when the modal initializes to check the Opportunity Stage. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<template>     


<lightning-quick-action-panel header="LWC Quick Action">
 
    {recordId}

</lightning-quick-action-panel>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';


    export default class QuickActionTest extends LightningElement {
    
    @api recordId;
  
 
    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('connectedCallback');        
        console.log('recordId: ' + this.recordId);           
    }
}
```

Here is the output: Record ID has value in the modal:
[image: modal]

And on the console log recordId is undefined.
[image: console]

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you're trying

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_lifecycle_hooks) the `connectedCallback` should be called after all API property values are initialized. If you still see this problem once you are working on a [Summer '21](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232) org, I suggest it is a bug that you should raise with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I contacted Salesforce support since I didn't find anything in their documentation.
Here is their answer :

The '@api recordId' will not be able to fetch the record Id directly here as the action type you are using is 'ScreenAction'.

You will have to fetch the recordId parameters from URL.
Refer below .js code.

```
==================================== 
import { LightningElement, api,wire } from 'lwc'; 
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation'; 

export default class QuickActionLWC extends LightningElement { 
currentPageReference = null; 
urlStateParameters = null; 

/* Params from Url */ 
recordId = null; 

@wire(CurrentPageReference) 
getStateParameters(currentPageReference) { 
if (currentPageReference) { 
this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference.state; 
this.setParametersBasedOnUrl(); 
} 
} 

setParametersBasedOnUrl() { 
this.recordId = this.urlStateParameters.recordId || null; 
} 
connectedCallback(){ 
console.log(this.recordId); 
} 
} 
==========================================
```

Here you can get the recordId from the URL.

Comment: Hi, I also reached out to Salesforce Support and they recommend to use Aura and LWC together to achieve this. Anyway I'll try this code. Thanks.